# GPUImage. How clean memory usage?

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

My Code:

```
let contrastfilter = GPUImageContrastFilter()
    contrastfilter.contrast = 1.4

let thresholdImageFilter = GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter()
thresholdImageFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 16.0

let filterGroup = GPUImageFilterGroup()
filterGroup.addFilter(contrastfilter)
filterGroup.addFilter(thresholdImageFilter)
contrastfilter.addTarget(thresholdImageFilter)

filterGroup.initialFilters = [ contrastfilter ]
filterGroup.terminalFilter = thresholdImageFilter

let resultImage = filterGroup.image(byFilteringImage: image)
```

After the execution of the code, I have the memory usage increases. How can I free up memory after execution?

Comment: After processing 5 photos, my memory usage increase to 200 MB and then not clean.